# Get status (checked or not) of multiple checkbox per row and their ids

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, checkbox

by clicking on Save, I would like to get all checkbox data per row

[image]

with something like this to insert all data into "rowList" (does not work)

```
        [...this.template.querySelectorAll('.inputTarget')]
        .forEach(element=> this.rowList.push({
            rowId:element.dataset.id, 
            Readyvalue:element(name='Ready').checked, 
            DoneValue:element(name='Ready').checked
        }));
```

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
      <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover slds-table_bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
              <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate slds-align_absolute-center">Name</div>
              </th>
              <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate slds-align_absolute-center">Ready</div>
              </th>
              <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate slds-align_absolute-center">Done</div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <template for:each={data} for:item="dt">
              <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={dt.Id}>
                <td>
                  <div>
                    TEST NAME
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="slds-checkbox slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-input class="inputTarget" type="checkbox" data-id={dt.Id} name="Ready"  data-type="Ready" checked={dt.Ready__c}></lightning-input>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="slds-checkbox slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-input class="inputTarget" type="checkbox" data-id={dt.Id} name="Done" data-type="Done" checked={dt.Done__c}></lightning-input>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <lightning-button
    label="Save"
    variant="brand"
    onclick={handleUpdate}
    ></lightning-button>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start from your data attribute:

```
this.rowList = data.map( (row) => ({
  id: row.Id,
  ready: this.template.querySelector(`*[data-id="${row.Id}"][data-type="Ready"]`).checked,
  done: this.template.querySelector(`*[data-id="${row.Id}"][data-type="Done"]`).checked
}) );
```

Map assigns a new array based on the callback provided that uses the existing array. From there, we just query the elements we need and get their `checked` attribute.

Comment: I encounter this error : Blocked attempt to invoke secure method with altered this

Comment: @Vneq Sorry. I forgot you couldn't do that. See my edit, it should be fine.

Comment: I replaced row.id with row.Id and it works, it's case sensitive, thank you

Comment: @Vneq Ah yes, I missed that as well, I didn't look at the markup close enough. Glad I was able to help, though.